# GCP - Can't access Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I've logged into the Google Cloud Platform console today and I can no longer see or create any entities in GCP Datastore. I don't use this interface very regularly, but I'm sure that I used to be able to see a list of the entities in the datastore, and be able to manually edit them.  Today I'm seeing no entities, and I get the following error message :

```
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
```

The link seems to point me off to a page that talks about integrating Google Sign-in into my web application - that doesn;t seem relevant to me at the moment - I'm just trying to use the GCP console itself

Comment: Have you tried from a private window?

Comment: Hi @AtefH. : If i try from a provate widnow I end up at a "Credentials" page. It has three sections : API Keys, OAuth 2.0 Client Id's and Service Accounts. The only entry I have here is in Service Accounts. It's also reminding me to Configure the OAuth 2 consent screen. Has something changed recently that means I have to configure this page? And which bits do I need to configure?

Comment: That's wired! Are you using a well-known browser like chrome, firefox, etc ? if yes try another browser or try to update your browser. it looks like that the platform is not detecting your browser! I am not sure. if nothing is working with you try to contact support

Comment: I'm using chrome - same thing happens in Firefox

Comment: I have no Idea, I would recommend reaching out to google support. Also Hopefully someone else here would have an idea.

Comment: What is the url you're using to access the GCP console page? Is it - ```https://console.cloud.google.com``` and then you select ```Datastore``` from the drop down menu on the left?

Comment: @NoCommandLine : I was using a different URL! ( One I've used for years as far as I know ). Using the URL you suggested has fixed things. i was going to `https://console.*developers*.google.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving details from comments section to full answer

1. The correct URL to access Cloud Console is `https://console.cloud.google.com` and then you select `Datastore` from the drop down menu on the left
2. OP was using an old url - `https://console.*developers*.google.com/`

Answer (score 0):

To Access any component in the GCP including datastore. You need to pass valid credential(key) or your pipeline should be processing using correct GCP credentials.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started